# pdflatex.exe on both dualcore-cores?

Tags: programming

Is it possible to load pdflatex on both dualcore-cores of my Intel Core2Duo-Processor? At the moment, pdflatex just uses one core while the second core stays idle.

I got a pretty big document of 200 pages with many non-eps-pictures included...

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: [3 years later] Since this question has been considered a duplicate in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/136658/how-to-make-pdflatex-multithreaded-when-shell-scape-is-enabled, I would like to point out that documents relying on `tikz` and either `external` lib or `standalone` package may benefit from multiple cores. Perhaps answers should be tracked under the linked question.

Answer (score 17):

TeX works in a linear way, with little or no room for parallellization. Besides that, `pdflatex` is written in a single-threaded fashion, so that won't be an option.

There are several options to speed-up building times:

1. `draft` does exactly what you expect from it, it produces a draft document: images are excluded, `microtype` is disabled, ...
2. you can use [`subfiles`](http://ctan.org/pkg/subfiles) or [`subdocs`](http://ctan.org/pkg/subdocs) (both clickable) to only rebuild the relevant parts of your document
3. comment sections you're not adapting at that moment

Comment: The linear nature of the typesetting process is the key: you can't start typesetting at the beginning and middle of a file at the same time!

Comment: That's true, but I've always felt that it could be possible to do two passes: one to do all macro expansions and collect figures / pictures / `tikz`, then parse those in parallel and in a second pass actually process / typeset all the actual text. But what the possible benefit could be, I don't know, optimization without benchmarking first is useless, so I don't know the actual bottlenecks. And there are probably issues with this idea :).

Comment: @Pieter: You're falling into the trap of thinking of TeX macros as similar to, for example, C ones. In TeX, you _cannot_ expand the macros without reference to what else is going on (see category codes, verbatim text, _etc._). So a scheme as you suggest is fundamentally not possible with the TeX model

Comment: That's why my first pass is expansion in a linear fashion, as it happens right now. But certain steps (for instance: including an image, which requires information on its dimensions) aren't performed *yet*, just the state at that moment is saved. Then those saved states are processed in parallel, modulo a dependency check.

Comment: @Pieter: In doesn't happen in a liner fashion. The expansion of any particular macro depends on the preceding material. So you cannot do 'first expand, then process'.

Comment: Certain actions that can be guaranteed to have no side effects (e.g. including a picture stream whose size is already known, embedding fonts, etc.) could indeed be parallelized. However, that would require a complete rewrite of the TeX program (which is written in a very idiosyncratic way, with many global variables etc.), something that AFAIK not even the LuaTeX team plans.

Comment: @Philipp: Quite apart from the technical questions about such an approach, I wonder how useful it would be on a practical level. The amount of work to do for the tasks which you point out could be put into a second thread is not necessarily a large part of the typesetting process. So there could be a lot of work for little actual gain.

Comment: Breaking up my large files into multiple small files is absolutely key to my LaTeX sanity. Generally, I have a seperate folder for figures, equations, proofs, sometimes sections. I don't use the subfile package, I just keep a harness.tex file which shares a preamble with the main file, and \input the file I'm working on. Saves me much time and aggravation, and makes using a VCS much more useful. It's also easier to reuse equations and so forth between documents.

Comment: There's plenty of room for parallelization with any "shell-escape" commands.