# How to make pdfLaTeX multithreaded when `--shell-escape` is enabled?

Tags: pgfplots, pdftex, tikz-external, shell-escape

I am using `\write18` enabled (or `--shell-escape`) with externalization to compile a bunch of `PGFplots`. The first run takes much time, and I noticed that `pdflatex` only runs on one CPU core. 
Is there any way to have `pdflatex` use multiple cores? (at least when `\write18` is enabled)

Comment: Since you explicitly mentioned the use of `external`: you can configure the external library to run in `mode=list and make`. The resulting makefile can be processed in parallel using `make -j 8 -f <file>.makefile` (in this case on 8 threads). Only feasible if you can resort to make, though...

Comment: Note that the keyword "external library" means that this question is no duplicate.

Comment: What OS are you using? At least on UNIX-like systems it may be enough to end the command line passed to `\write18` with an ampersand character (`&`) to have the shell spawn a new process for the external command.

Comment: Could you give a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem, in particular, allows us to experiment with your method of "compiling a bunch of PGFplots"?

Comment: @ChristianFeuersänger Could you add your comment as an answer? Furthermore, I looked into the code and I think that indeed, it might not be too much work and a nice addition to allow `\write18{\pgf@tempa\string&}` on systems that support this. The only problem would be not to include the image immediately afterwards, but wait at the end of the first run for all images to finish and then include them in the second run. On systems with several cores, this is probably much faster than waiting for every image to finish.

Comment: @StephanLehmke sorry, I fear that I have seen your message, but could not react right-away at that time. And than I forgot about it.

Comment: @StephanLehmke your feature request with asynchronous processing sounds interesting; but I fear that it would easily run out-of-control unless you restrict the number of background processes. And that, in turn, sounds like a very complicated method in TeX ... compiling twice would be simple. If you want to experiment with the code; feel free to do so.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The `externalize` in tikz may generated individual picture for every `\begin{tikzpicture}...\end{tikzpicture}`.

- `\usepgfplotslibrary{external}` let all pgf-plots outside of the compile.

Let pdflatex know those pictures are compiled with **make**.

- `\tikzexternalize[mode=list and make]` let tikz to know we would use the `make`.
  Because at present only the `make` support multi-thread.

I'm lazy to set the name for every pgfplots figure, so I let it done by system.

- `external/system call` set names for individual picture file, or the pdflatex doesn't know what file name should be set.
  (Origin code is from package tikz&pgf Manual for Version 2.10 page 345.)

My tex file is named `test.tex`

```
    \documentclass{standalone}

    \usepackage{pgfplots} %use tikz based pgfplots
      \usepgfplotslibrary{external}
        \tikzexternalize[mode=list and make]
        \tikzset{external/system call={pdflatex \tikzexternalcheckshellescape
          -halt-on-error -interaction=batchmode -jobname "\image" "\texsource"}
        } % to let pdflatex work
    %% compile picture: pdflatex --shell-escape xxxxxxx.tex

    \begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[ xlabel=$x$, ylabel={$f(x) = x^2 - x +4$} ] 
      \addplot {x^2 - x +4}; 
    \end{axis} 
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{loglogaxis}[xlabel=Cost,ylabel=Gain]
      \addplot[color=red,mark=x] coordinates 
      { (10,100) (20,150) (40,225) (80,340) (160,510) (320,765) (640,1150) };
    \end{loglogaxis}
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \end{document}
```

After first `pdflatex` compiling, do the `make -j 4 -f test.makefile`.
`4` compiles the pictures with 4 thread.

Then run `pdflatex` second time.

The option `--shell-escape` also work fine in my system.

My system is:

1. Win 7(x64) + Miktex 2.9 + make under cygwin environment
2. Linux(x64) + Texlive2013 + make

Comment: Interesting, but could you elaborate what you are doing here? What is the sense of tikzexternalize ?

Comment: I try explain the option I used, But it looks a bit weird in style.

Comment: This approach does not seem to work when the `tikzpicture`s are imported with an `\input{file.tikz}` command. But maybe it's just a matter of properly naming the imported files.

Comment: Reviewing chapter 53 of the [pgfplots manual](http://mirror.utexas.edu/ctan/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf) may clarify some of the techniques @selwyndd21 is using here.