# Missing *.sty files when running \tikzexternalize[mode=list and make]

Tags: tikz-pgf, packages, tikz-external

Having recently discovered the use of the `tikzexternalize` library, I decided to multithread the compilation of my tikz images using the method suggested in this thread: [1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/136658/how-to-make-pdflatex-multithreaded-when-shell-escape-is-enabled).

However, I am having issues when doing this when loading certain other packages such as `microtype`, `algorithm2e`, etc. Review of the log file during the tikz externalization process shows that `*.sty` files are missing and the required modules cannot be found.

MWE is as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{todonotes}

\usepackage{pgfplots} %use tikz based pgfplots
  \usepgfplotslibrary{external}
  \tikzset{external/disable dependency files}
    \tikzexternalize[mode=list and make, prefix=tikz/]

    \tikzset{external/system call={lualatex \tikzexternalcheckshellescape
      -halt-on-error -interaction=batchmode -jobname "\image" "\texsource"}
    } % to let pdflatex work
%% compile picture: pdflatex --shell-escape xxxxxxx.tex

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\todo}[2][]{\tikzexternaldisable\@todo[#1]{#2}\tikzexternalenable}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
some text

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ xlabel=$x$, ylabel={$f(x) = x^2 - x +4$} ] 
  \addplot {x^2 - x +4}; 
\end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{loglogaxis}[xlabel=Cost,ylabel=Gain]
  \addplot[color=red,mark=x] coordinates 
  { (10,100) (20,150) (40,225) (80,340) (160,510) (320,765) (640,1150) };
\end{loglogaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Setup is Win 7 (x64) + TeXlive 2014 + Texmaker + Cygwin (make)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: I have edited your English a little to help make your question clearer. Please feel free to undo anything which you feel misrepresents your intended meaning. (I tried to be quite conservative but I also tried to rewrite things which didn't really make sense.)

Answer (score 1):

I would guess that this is due to your Windows/cygwin setup: perhaps the search paths are set up incorrectly or the latex installation gets confused.

In fact, missing `.sty` files should be entirely unrelated to `external`. The fact that you still see such messages indicate a severe project setup problem. 
I would bet that the file does not compile even if you disable `external` altogether.

Perhaps you have compiled the main file from within your Windows TeX installation and the make invocation uses the `linux` / `cygwin` TeX installation? Perhaps the cygwin TeX installation does not have `microtype`.

Since this is just a (hopefully) good guess, my answer would be to verify your setup; in particular with regard to the question "Which TeX installation is being used".

If this answer turns out to be a dead-end, I would like to ask you to give more detail on how you compile, optimally with the cygwin search path environment.