# Tikz external with beamer animations

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, tikz-external, animations, shell-escape

I'm trying to speed-up compilation of my multi-tikz `.tex` file.

I found [this topic](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/136658/how-to-make-pdflatex-multithreaded-when-shell-escape-is-enabled) and successfully applied the solution ; unfortunately, it doesn't work for animations inside the `tikzfigure`: Only the first view of the animation is rendered on the final pdf.

**Question**: Is there a way to make tikz external work with beamer's animations?

The tikzset I use for my animations is the following (found also on texSE):

```
\tikzset{
    invisible/.style={opacity=0},
    visible on/.style={alt={#1{}{invisible}}},
    alt/.code args={<#1>#2#3}{%
        \alt<#1>{\pgfkeysalso{#2}}{\pgfkeysalso{#3}} % \pgfkeysalso doesn't change the path
    },
}
```

Here is a full document that illustrate the issue:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{pgfplots}              % handle plots
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}
\usepgfplotslibrary{external}
    \tikzexternalize[mode=list and make, prefix=tikz/]
    \tikzset{external/system call={pdflatex \tikzexternalcheckshellescape
        -halt-on-error -interaction=batchmode -jobname "\image" "\texsource"}
    } % to let pdflatex work

\tikzset{
    invisible/.style={opacity=0},
    visible on/.style={alt={#1{}{invisible}}},
    alt/.code args={<#1>#2#3}{%
        \alt<#1>{\pgfkeysalso{#2}}{\pgfkeysalso{#3}} % \pgfkeysalso doesn't change the path
    },
}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[draw] at (0,0) {auie};
        \pause
        \node[draw] at (1,0) {tsrn};
        \node[draw,visible on=<3->] at (1,1) {vdlj};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please provide us with a complete minimal example, i.e. document that starts with `\dcoumentclass` and ends with `\end{document}`. BT, perhaps something like [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/119440/121799) helps or is at least a good starting point.

Comment: created a complete minimal example

Comment: Thanks! Notice that `visible on` etc. is part of the very useful library `overlay-beamer-styles`, whose only disadvantage is that nobody can recall its name. ;-)

Answer (score 6):

Thanks for your MWE! Here is an example entirely based on [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/119440/121799). You will see that if you compile it the second time, the external pictures will be loaded, so compilation is faster.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
%\url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/119428/86}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{external}
\usetikzlibrary{overlay-beamer-styles}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\overlaynumber}{\number\beamer@slideinframe}
\tikzset{
  beamer externalizing/.style={%
    execute at end picture={%
      \tikzifexternalizing{%
        \ifbeamer@anotherslide
        \pgfexternalstorecommand{\string\global\string\beamer@anotherslidetrue}%
        \fi
      }{}%
    }%
  },
  external/optimize=false
}
\let\orig@tikzsetnextfilename=\tikzsetnextfilename
\renewcommand\tikzsetnextfilename[1]{\orig@tikzsetnextfilename{#1-\overlaynumber}}
\makeatother

\tikzset{every picture/.style={beamer externalizing}}

\tikzexternalize

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t]{\texttt{overlay-beamer-styles} and \texttt{externalize}}
\begin{itemize}
  \item<1-> Image 1
  \item<2-> Image 2
  \item<3-> Image 3
\end{itemize}
  \tikzsetnextfilename{figure}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (1) {Overlay 1};
    \draw[-latex,visible on={<2->}] (1.east) -- ++ (1,0) node[right] (2) {Overlay 2};
    \draw[-latex,visible on={<3->}] (2.east) -- ++ (1,0) node[right] (3) {Overlay 3};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: it's recompiling the whole document (with figures) even if the change is not in a tikzpicture.
BTW, the figures are wrong when I set `\setbeameroption{show notes on second screen}`

Comment: @Jav No, this is *not* true. It only recompiles when you change the figures. BTW, what is `\setbeameroption{show notes on second screen}`? On my distribution that just causes an error.

Comment: from pgfpages : allows to create a double sized frame with the frame on the left, and the notes on the right

Comment: @Jav Either make qualified statements or please refrain from posting random comments. I just told you that your command throws an error. So I do not think that your comment addresses this in any way. And the first part of your above comment is just not true.

Comment: Sorry from beeing unclear buddy, I have trouble replicating the (many) issues I face with advanced beamer usage. It's not random comment, it's an answer to your question « BTW wat is… ». I'm telling you what it is.

Comment: @Jav You are making statements that cannot be reproduced. I tested my code 20 times and *cannot* confirm what you are saying. And then you tell that the figures are wrong if you use `\setbeameroption{show notes on second screen}`, but this command simply causes an error. What should I say? I just think that you do not run my code at all.

Comment: @Jav `\tikzifexternalizing{}{\setbeameroption{show notes on second screen}}`

Answer (score 2):

The [previous answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/454002/117275) solves the MWE in the question, but my experience is that the `visible on=<overlay specification>` tikzset and overlay-beamer-styles are not compatible with tikzexternalize when the figure contains transparency. Note this occurs even when setting `opacity=1`. Using the standard beamer overlay specification (e.g. `\draw<1->`), however, works as expected, and therefore may be a more general solution.

[image]

Oddly, the incorrect behavior is a bit different depending if the transparency is in a graphic included with `\includegraphics` vs a tikz drawing. Based on this limitation, it seems better to avoid the overlay-beamer-styles format or the "visible on" tikzset if externalizing figures with transparency might be needed.

Modified MWE to highlight this issue:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
%\url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/119428/86}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{external}
\usetikzlibrary{overlay-beamer-styles}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\overlaynumber}{\number\beamer@slideinframe}
\tikzset{
  beamer externalizing/.style={%
    execute at end picture={%
      \tikzifexternalizing{%
        \ifbeamer@anotherslide
        \pgfexternalstorecommand{\string\global\string\beamer@anotherslidetrue}%
        \fi
      }{}%
    }%
  },
  external/optimize=false
}
\let\orig@tikzsetnextfilename=\tikzsetnextfilename
\renewcommand\tikzsetnextfilename[1]{\orig@tikzsetnextfilename{#1-\overlaynumber}}
\makeatother

\tikzset{every picture/.style={beamer externalizing}}

\tikzexternalize

\begin{document}

  \begin{frame}{\texttt{overlay-beamer-styles} and \texttt{externalize}}
    \tikzsetnextfilename{figure0}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
       \node (1) {Overlay 1};
       \draw[-latex,visible on={<2->},opacity=0.5] (1.east) -- ++ (1,0) node[right] (2) {Overlay 2};
       \draw[-latex,visible on={<3->},opacity=1] (2.east) -- ++ (1,0) node[right] (3) {Overlay 3};
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{frame}

  \begin{frame}{\texttt{overlay specification} and \texttt{externalize}}
    \tikzsetnextfilename{figure1}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \node (1) {Overlay 1};
      \draw<2->[-latex,opacity=0.5] (1.east) -- ++ (1,0) node[right] (2) {Overlay 2};
      \draw<3->[-latex,opacity=1] (2.east) -- ++ (1,0) node[right] (3) {Overlay 3};
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```