# How to make LuaLaTeX multithreaded when `--shell-escape` is enabled?

Tags: pgfplots, luatex, tikz-external, shell-escape

I found this thread:

[How to make pdfLaTeX multithreaded when `--shell-escape` is enabled?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/136658/how-to-make-pdflatex-multithreaded-when-shell-escape-is-enabled)

It works great.
But when I change to LuaLaTeX there is still just 1 cpu active.

So is there a way to achive this with LuaLaTeX aswell?

Comment: @HenriMenke, I don't think this is a duplicate because OP is asking (most likely) for multithreaded externalization of `tikzpicture` environments, which **is** possible, as is described in the answer to the linked question.

Comment: @davidgrills, could you elaborate a bit more *when* only 1 CPU is active? During the (normal) LuaLaTeX run or during processing the makefile? Could you please also add an MWE which is not working for you? Then we have a chance to either replicate your problem or it is fine for us ...

Answer (score 0):

Oh sorry guys,
I found out, that I looked wrong and everything works fine.

I was looking for multithreading while make.

This works for me with

```
make -j 4 -f mwe.makefile
```

Here is the file:

```
\listfiles
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usetikzlibrary{external} 
\tikzexternalize[mode=list and make]
\begin{document}
  \input{plot.tex}
  \input{plot.tex}
  \input{plot.tex}
   \input{plot.tex}
  \input{plot.tex}
  \input{plot.tex}
  \input{plot.tex}
  \input{plot.tex}
   \input{plot.tex}
  \input{plot.tex}
  \input{plot.tex}  
\end{document}
```

The plot.tex is just a pgfplots plot with a lot of points.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot
  table[row sep=crcr]{%
0.00158079699940572 0\\
142.183864004999    0\\

...

160.419964085   2523.5\\
160.420948376999    2526.5\\
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
```

Comment: That is what I would have expected. Do you agree that we either mark the question as duplicate or -- even better -- you simply delete the question?

Comment: I thought that someone else could find the post and see that it do work with lualatex, what is also a good information.